# Python: (sub) String equivalence vs List fast membership testing

Tags: python

Can somebody explain to me the following (python 2.7)

Two string numbers, from a parsed file:

'410.9'
'410.9 ' (Notice the trailing space)

```
A_LIST = ['410.9 ']

'410.9' in '410.9 '
True

'410.9' in A_LIST
False
```

No problem working around this - just trying to understand why it is so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is correct behavior because:

```
  >>>'410.9'=='410.9 '
  >>>False
```

and when you cheking list for a membership of a certain item you are actually doing something like that:

```
...
for item in A_LIST:
  if item == '410.9':
    return True
...
```

Answer (score 6):

`in` with two strings checks or a substring, whereas `in` with a list checks for membership.

What you want is something like `[x for x in A_LIST if '419' in x]`

Comment: This is what I need to avoid the workaround - voted up - but gave the answer to Vader for defining 'membership' as ==.

Answer (score 5):

The first test is testing whether the first string is a substring of the second, and the second test is testing whether the string is a member of the given list. Since it is not exactly equal to any member of the list, the second test returns false.